# sed find and replace with n instances using regex

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a file containing some lines which look like this:-

```
DUMMY name, 4, 6, 5*0, 34, 322552
DUMMY same, 4, 6, 2*2, 34, 322552
```

I want to replace all instances of `"m*n"` with `m` repeated values of `n`, i.e. replace `"5*0,"` with `"0, 0, 0, 0, 0,"`, and `"2*2"` with `"2, 2,"`, so the output for the above lines should look like:-

```
DUMMY name, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34, 322552
DUMMY same, 4, 6, 2, 2, 34, 322552
```

So far I have managed to identify all instances of "m*n" and can replace with m or (in the line below) n using sed:-

```
sed -r 's/([0-9])(\*)([0-9]),/\3,/g'
```

but I can't work out how to make it repeat the regex `\3 m` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily by using `gnu-awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {for (f=1; f<=NF; f++) if (match($f, /([0-9]+)\*([0-9]+)/, a)) 
      {s=a[2]; for (i=1; i<a[1]; i++) s = s OFS a[2]; $f=s} } 1' file
DUMMY name, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34, 322552
DUMMY same, 4, 6, 2, 2, 34, 322552
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ( split($i,a,/\*/) > 1 ) {
            for (j=1;j<=a[1];j++) {
                $i = (j>1 ? $i OFS : "") a[2]
            }
        }
    }
}
1' file
DUMMY name, 4, 6, 5*0, 34, 322552
DUMMY same, 4, 6, 2*2, 34, 322552
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. perl on the command line.

```
cat filename | perl -ne '$mystring = $_ ;if (~/(\d+)\*(\d+)/) { $a = join(",",map{" $2"}(1..$1));$mystring =~ s/ \d+\*\d+/$a/;print $mystring}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as you found out the generic vanilla sed does not support shorthand repeat syntax on the RHS, so to use sed you have to handle each case:

`sed 's/9\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/8\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/7\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/6\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/5\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/4\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1/;s/4\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1/;s/3\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1/;s/2\*\(.\)/\1, \1/;s/1\*\(.\)/\1/;'`

Eg.
`echo "DUMMY name, 4, 6, 5*0, 34, 322552" | sed 's/9\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/8\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/7\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/6\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/5\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/4\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1/;s/4\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1/;s/3\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1/;s/2\*\(.\)/\1, \1/;s/1\*\(.\)/\1/;'`

```
Output:
DUMMY name, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34, 322552
```

`echo "DUMMY same, 4, 6, 2*2, 34, 322552" | sed 's/9\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/8\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/7\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/6\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/5\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1, \1/;s/4\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1/;s/4\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1, \1/;s/3\*\(.\)/\1, \1, \1/;s/2\*\(.\)/\1, \1/;s/1\*\(.\)/\1/;'`

```
Output:
DUMMY same, 4, 6, 2, 2, 34, 322552
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a nagging feeling that I was missing something obvious, but from what you say its sed that is missing something!